# How do I use the `Function Call Operator` to load `rvalue` types to my object?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, move, rvalue, function-call-operator

I have a class like this:

```
template<typename T>
class MyClass
{
    public:
        // ...
              T && operator()(uint64_t i, uint64_t j);  // I want to add a member function like this.
              T &  operator()(uint64_t i, uint64_t j);
        const T &  operator()(uint64_t i, uint64_t j) const;
        // ...
};
```

While I was revising the code, I realized that the stored object of type `T` is being copied every time it tries to set an object to an `(i,j)` position. I would like to use move semantics and avoid this unnecessary copying if it is possible? Is it possible to solve this by adding a third operator like in the code above?

My aim is to access a `MyClass` instance like this in the code:

```
MyClass<Element> myclass;
// ...
Element element;                        // 'Element' is movable.
// ...
myclass(2, 3) = std::move(element);     // 'element' is no longer needed, it can be moved.
```

How can I do this?

Comment: You can't overload on return type alone, so simply adding the operator is impossible.

Comment: Also, I don't see why you'd need to add this operator. Applying `std::move` to the element should call the move assignment operator. Is `operator=(Element&&)` defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you can't overload based on the return type. However, this is not your problem since you don't need extra overloads of the subscript operator.

In order to avoid unnecessary copies and since `class Element` objects are movable, you could use `std::swap` instead of direct assignment.

```
std::swap(myclass(2, 3), element);
```

Since C++11 `std::swap` avoids the unnecessary copy because it uses move semantics.

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Thank you.